# Codeigniter Too many connection __construct()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CI 3.X. Now in my app I using multiple database. Now my hosting server allows max 100 connections, So my app gets down.

In my database configurations I have kept **PCONNECT to FALSE** .

Now My Structure is as follow:

I have a base controller **MY_Controller** which extends to **CI_Controller**.

Then I have a **Customer_Controller** which extends to MY_Controller.

In Customer_Controller I load my secondary database. And this Customer_Controller lives in libraries folder.

All my other controller extend to this controller.

So where Am I going wrong ? Why does my MySQL sever gets this error ???

the error i get it:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 202
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /application/core/MY_Controller.php Line: 7 Function:
>   __construct
>
> File: /application/libraries/Admin_Controller.php Line: 7 Function:
>   __construct
>
> File: /application/controllers/admin/Dashboard.php Line: 16 Function:
>   __construct
>
> File: index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: As the error suggests it's a MySQL related error- too many connections. Your code is fine.

Comment: do i need to call the __destructor and close DB Connection some where @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim

Comment: I think you should try that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to increase the value of `max_connections` in your MySQL configuration file. Possible location for the file is: `/etc/my.cnf`.

On the file increase the value of `max_connections` system variable:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=500
```

Alternatively, you can also turn off persistent connection from MySQL.

```
[MySQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mysql.allow_persistent=Off
```

Comment: But i dont have the access to PHP.ini file on hosting server

Comment: @Rajan are you on a shared hosting?

Comment: So, you don't have the permission. And shared hosting has limited resource, that's why you are getting this error. Consider upgrading your current package or if possible go for cloud hosting: https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=3a44ac1c4869