# mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections mysqli_driver.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**ISSUE**

Hi everyone, I looked for the solution in stackoverflow but i not found it. I'm working with CodeIgniter framework and since a few months i got this error.

**SOLUTION TRIED**

Change max_connection in my database (phpmyadmin)

Verify close of database connections

**QUESTIONS**

Do you think i need to change dbdriver to pdo, I currently use mysqli?

Should I put $db['default']['pconnect'] to true for the persistent connection?

**POST VISITED**

[Codeigniter Too many connection __construct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927984/codeigniter-too-many-connection-construct)

[Persistant connections not working with mysqli driver in codeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759081/persistant-connections-not-working-with-mysqli-driver-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Too many connection \_\_construct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927984/codeigniter-too-many-connection-construct)

Comment: I already saw that post but it doesn't resolve my issue look at solutions tried in my post

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adjusting the MySQL variable `wait_timeout` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)) to a lower value - try 300 to start with. (The default value is 28800.)

The value is set by editing the MySQL configuration file and restarting MySQL. Where that file is found and what it is called will depend on your operating system. The file is often named `my.cnf` or `mysqld.cnf`.